# How to require users of a Windows Share to authenticate before showing contents

Tags: windows, networking, windows-authentication

I am trying to setup global shares across our entire network, and allow people from remote locations with AD Credentials to have access to our local shares. However rather than authenticating them it is literally just allowing them to do whatever they want, delete, create, etc. Obviously for security reasons this is a huge problem.

What is the proper procedure say for example using an IIS Website's document root, and sharing it across the network or internet, and making it so that it forces a user (local or remote) to authenticate against active directory.

I have researched this issue and using tutorials and my common knowledge of the platform am not able to come to a resolution. Currently I have shares blocking "Everyone" until we resolve these issues.

I've also noticed that our "sysvol" and "netlogin" directories are wide open. Shouldn't those automatically be secured by Windows? Or is that not something to worry about?

Comment: ` "sysvol" and "netlogin" directories are wide open.` - Unless you change things that simply isn't true.  The 'share-level' permissions are relatively permissive, but the NTFS access control lists are pretty tightly locked down on those folders.  Share level permissions do not grant privileges in any way, they only can take th em away. NTFS ACLs are required to grant access to a resource.

Comment: I didn't change anything on this server. It is literally as was installed from the CD, all we did was promote it to a domain controller and load our files onto it, and created the shares to those files.

Comment: You need to be more specific about these 'remote users' that are getting access without authentication.  Are the computers members of the same domain/forest?  Are they logging into the local computer with a Domain account?  If yes to both, **then they authenticated**.

Comment: No, these user are on a different network (in this case i'm using my home network, different connection, subnet, and provider), and entering the public IP address as the computer name, and without username and password authentication, i'm able to get into every shared folder.

Comment: Is your username and password the same as your username/password on the remote system?  If so, then windows will automatically authenticate you.

Comment: No, our usernames and passwords are different across all our systems. So no Administrator accounts have the same password as another.